# file_get_contents over https displays garbage

Tags: php

I am trying to download uploaded files over https and, while the files themselves download, they cannot be viewed.

I have tried JPG, DOC and XLS files and all give the same problem and, in all cases, if I download via FTP they open perfectly and they open fine in the browser pre-download using the script.

Here is a subset of the script showing the code I am trying to use? Any idea why it downloads garbage?

```
$_file = sanitiseData($_GET['doc']);
$filename = '/doc_uploads/'.$_file; 
if (file_exists($filename)) { 
header('Content-type:image/jpg');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$_file.'"');
echo file_get_contents($filename);
} else { 
echo "The file $_file does not exist"; 
}
```

Here is a sample of the garbage when trying to view a downloaded JPG via browser:

����JFIF��;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 90 ��C     ��C       ��R�"��    ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������    ���w!1AQaq"2�B���� #3R�br� $4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������?�P��q\�O�^�-�C�z�z����o�N��P;��.i�~k+Զ���|�7`�'e����G�>+���_�6�%�Ԓ��Y�w���P�~.�����2E��  ��"��ڗȌ��ms����[���?��%|"�R5�s�c������=?V��>���IG�=?V��>���I_Q@w����o���������o����������=?V��>���IG�=?V��>���I_Q@w����o���������o����������=?V��>���IG�=?V��>���I_Q@w����o���������o����������=?V��>���IG�=?V��>���I_Q@w����o���������o����������=?V��>���IG�=?V��>���I_Q@w����o���������o����������=?V��>���IG�=?V��>���I_Q@w����o���������o����������=?V��>���IG�=?V��>���I_Q@w����o���������o����������=?V��>���IG�=?V��>���I_Q@w����o���������o����������=?V��>���IG�=?V��>���I_Q@w����o���������o����������=?V��>���IG�=?V��>���I_Q@w����o���������o����������=GU��>���� �N�v������%|!E~�xO� �ỹx_P����j(�z����_

Comment: What actually is the content of these files you talk about? I mean, give a sample of the garbage.

Comment: I would recommend `readfile(...)` instead of `file_get_contents(...)` as `file_get_contents(...)` returns a string whereas `readfile(...)` effectively returns the binary data despite it saying it returns `typeof(int)`

Comment: (`readfile(...)`)[http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php] has some nice info on how to do a download script. Just change `application/octet-stream` to `image/jpeg`

Comment: readfile behaves exactly the same way, I am beginning to think this is a server or PHP config issue

Comment: @ColeJohnson BINGO! That worked - I used the code example php.net and it works! Thank you! I cannot mark your response as the answer but it did the trick for me!

Comment: @ColeJohnson `file_get_contents()` is binary-safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to use [readfile(...)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php). PHP's website has a nice example that should help you. I use it on my website and it works like a charm:

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
    // Inform browser that this is a force-download
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    // Inform browser that data can be binary in addition to text
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    // Inform browser that this page expires immediately so that an update to the file will still work.
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    // Push actual file.
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes are causing you to output the string `"$filename"` instead of the variable value `$filename`.

```
echo file_get_contents($filename);
```

Though we don't see the function `sanitiseData()`, we assume it is properly filtering out strings that could be used for path injection  like `../`.

#### Addendum:

I'll note that the correct MIME type for a jpeg is `image/jpeg`, rather than `image/jpg`.  That is likely going to cause you problems too.

Comment: That didn't make any difference unfortunately - sanisitiseData() is used for all data input across the whole site.

Comment: I find it hard to believe this made no difference at all, since `'$filename'` is an entirely different thing than `$filename`.  Remove the `Content-disposition` header and see if you call the script via browser, does it just display the image on screen?]

Comment: I had tried this before - it displays the garbage above (plus more but there was no point showing it all) when I remove the two header references

Comment: `image/jpeg` is the correct mime type for a jpg image, not `image/jpg`.